# как отловить элемент в jquery из select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Проблема такая на до что бы когда пользователь выбирает select определенный option то появляется модальное окно ну или атрибуты html
вот код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#act".select()).click(function() {
    $('#select').prepend('<option value="10">Добавить в самое начала Select</option>');

    
  });
});
```

```css
#hideModal{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form" id="form">
<label class="mr-sm-2" for="act">ДЕЙСТВИЯ</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-md custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="act" id="act">
    <option value="Срочно связаться" id="clickShow">Срочно связаться</option>
    <option value="01 ку">01 ку</option>
    <option value="02 02">02 02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
  </select>  

  <div class="col-md-5" id="hideModal">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="content">История событий</label>
    <textarea class="form-control bg-field" id="content" name="historyEvent" rows="5"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="calendar">Выберите дату:</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control bg-field" id="calendar" name="calendar">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
  <label for="calendar">Выберите время:</label>
  <input name="time" class="form-control bg-field" type="time" name="calendar"/>
  </div>
  </div>  
  </form>
```

так же пробовал так

```html
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var act = $("#act").val();
    var name = "03";
    if (act == name) {
     $("#hideModal").show();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы отловить выбор какого-то элемента, есть событие `onchange`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#act").change(function() {
    alert( $(this).val() )
  });
});
```

```css
#hideModal {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form" id="form">
  <label class="mr-sm-2" for="act">ДЕЙСТВИЯ</label>
  <select class="form-control form-control-md custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" name="act" id="act">
    <option value="Срочно связаться" id="clickShow">Срочно связаться</option>
    <option value="01 ку">01 ку</option>
    <option value="02 02">02 02</option>
    <option value="03">03</option>
  </select>

  <div class="col-md-5" id="hideModal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="content">История событий</label>
      <textarea class="form-control bg-field" id="content" name="historyEvent" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="calendar">Выберите дату:</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control bg-field" id="calendar" name="calendar">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="calendar">Выберите время:</label>
      <input name="time" class="form-control bg-field" type="time" name="calendar" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

`"#act".select()` - нельзя так обращаться. Такого не существует. Вы можете написать `$('#act:selected')`

Comment: спасибо вам большое то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Во первых я бы использовал так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#act option").select(function() {
   $("#act").prepend('<option value="10">Добавить в самое начала Select</option>');
  });
});
```

в состоянии select может быть только тэг option, следовательно нужно применять к нему. А добавлять код нужно в начало тэга select, у которого id='act', а вы прибавляете в начало какого-то тэга, у которого id="select", я такого не нашел в вашем html коде.